# FastScroll in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, fastscroll

**Any suggestions on implementing quickscroll AKA fastScroll on React Native?**

I'm trying to implement quick scrolling -- AKA fast scrolling -- on a FlatList in React Native and I'm running into a lot of issues.

The existing libraries, react-native-quick-scroll & react-native-alphabetlistview don't perform too well when scrolling and are rather dated.

I'm looking for something similar to the screenshot below, where the user can scroll normally by touching the list items but also scroll much faster using the scroll bar on the right side.

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: FastScroll Example]

Comment: Were you able to find a library for this?

Answer (score 0):

**React Native TableView** might work, using the `sectionIndexTitlesEnabled` property, but it is iOS-only: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tableview